# Как отключить функцию при маленькой ширине экрана

Tags: javascript

есть функция, и нужно, чтобы она выключалась при ширине экрана меньше 1080 пикселей, а включалась при ширине больше 1080 пикселей. Такой код мне не помог:

```
var screenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

  if (screenWidth <= 1080 ) {
  window.onscroll = false; 
} else if(screenWidth > 1080 {
  window.onscroll = true;
}
```

еще постарался написать такой код для определения ключевой переменной

```
 var  picInd = scrolled <= 1 && screenWidth >= 1080 ? 0 : scrolled > 8 && screenWidth >= 1080 ? 9 : scrolled;
```

но тоже не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитай тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia про функцию (или это метод, просто JS настолько гибкий, что иногда в нем методы являются функциями или наооборот) `window.matchMedia`

Пример:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  window.onresize = function(){if(window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 2200px)").matches){
 screenWidthUpdate = null;
 console.log("function deleted");
  }
 }
}

var screenWidthUpdate = function(){
   document.write("hello <hr/>");
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Это не будет работать при ресайзе окна.

Comment: @PavelMayorov  Убери минус. Оберни весь этот код в `window.onresize = function(){}`

Comment: @EugenEray нет смысла оборачивать onload внутрь onresize. Минус не уберу пока ответ не станет рабочим.

Comment: @PavelMayorov  Ок поправил. Я с телефона сижу - сниппет не могу так просмотреть.

Comment: @EugenEray все равно не работает

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ок с компа зайду.

Comment: @PavelMayorov  А вроде Stack Owerflow не адаптивный, потому, что когда я уменьшал браузер, у меня сниппет iFrame не уменьшился. Я попробую на фидле.